# Adding OpenStreetMap maps to Python application

Tags: python, openstreetmap, offline

I want to add OpenStreetMap maps to my Python application with the limitation that it must work offline. The obvious choice is to render map tiles using Mapnik but I really do not want to force the user to install (and configure) a Postgres server. I could potentially import the data into a SQLite database using ogr2ogr but that would require me to write a new map rendering style from scratch.

Bundling pre-rendered tiles with the application is not an option due to the amount of storage space that would require.

Are there any other options that I have missed?

Comment: Did you already dig in the OpenStreetMap wiki? For example the [rendering](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) wiki page mentions a few python solutions.

Comment: I can not say for sure that I have not missed anything but all the alternatives I have found so far requires me to either use a Postgres database or to write my own rendering style from scratch.